# filtered algebra vs graded algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

**BACKGROUND**

When reading Okounkov-Olshanski's paper about shifted symmetric functions, they define $\Lambda^*$ to be the algebra of shifted symmetric functions.

They say that $\Lambda_n^*$ is a filtered by degree of polynomials and $$\phi: \Lambda^*_{n+1}\to \Lambda^*_n : x_{n+1}\mapsto 0$$ is a morphism of filtered algebras.

They define $$\Lambda^* = \varprojlim\Lambda^*_n$$
taken in the category of filtered algebras, with respect to the morphisms defined above.

**MY QUESTIONS**

1. I have seen that when we work with the algebra of symmetric functions, we need to take the inverse limit in the category of graded rings in order to have the necessary elements. Otherwise there are elements that are not symmetric functions on the limit. Why do we take the inverse limit in the category of filtered algebras and not in the category of graded algebras (when we are working with shifted symmetric)?
2. I have seen that the filtered algebras are a generalization of the graded algebras. Could anyone explain it to me in a clearer way?

Comment: A filtration if an algebra gives rise to a graded algebra. The properties of graded algebras are easy to see, those properties are frequently implied for the filtered algebra. Often this structural approach obfuscates a simple argument with leading terms.

Comment: You could probably take the limit in the category of graded algebras with filtration-preserving algebra homomorphisms, too, if you treat the polynomials as polynomials in the $x_i-i $ variables. I suspect it's a deliberate choice by the authors to avoid doing this, in order to avoid having a nonstandard concept of homogenity muddy the waters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer my own question after some time of investigation.

1. We take the inverse limit in the category of filtered algebras since
   it makes no sense to take it in the category of graded algebras. The morphisms
   $\rho_n:(\Lambda^*(n))^k \to (\Lambda^*(n-1))^k$ are not compatible
   with the specialization $x_n\mapsto 0$. In the new variables, we
   have constants that do not go to zero. Hence, we may obtain things
   that are not homogeneous of degree $k$. (Taking the inverse limit in
   the category of algebras would give us more than what we want.
   Infinite products would be allowed and we could have things that are
   not finite sum of the elements of the basis).
2. For a short explanation of what filtered algebras are and how to
   define the corresponding graded algebra, I will give the two
   definitions. A filtered algebra is a generalization of the notion of
   a graded algebra.

   A **filtered algebra over the field $k$** is an algebra
   $A$ over $k$ which has an increasing sequence
   $\{0\}\subset F_0\subset F_1\subset\cdots \subset F_i\subset\cdots\subset A$ of substructures of $A$ such that: $$A=\bigcup_{i\in
   \mathbb{N}}F_i$$

   and that is compatible with the multiplication in the following
   sense:

   $$\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N},\ F_n \cdot F_m\subset F_{n+m}.$$

   Now, let $A$ be a filtered algebra. Then, its **corresponding graded algebra** $\mathrm{gr}(A)$ is defined as $$\mathrm{gr}(A)= \bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N}
   \frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}$$ where $\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}=G_n$ and
   $G_0=F_0$. It is also compatible with the multiplication in the
   following sense:

   $$\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N},\ G_n \cdot G_m\subset G_{n+m}.$$